# How can i start react site from different static html

Tags: reactjs

I have a react project. When I start with npm start, it starts with index.html.
But I want to start with xxx.html(static HTML). 
the static xxx page includes a button, when i press the button, it will redirect normal react page.

I have tried to change start-url in manifest.js , but nothing changed.

```
  "start_url": "./index_react.html",
```

How can I change that? thank you in advance.

Comment: is this using `create-react-app` ?

Comment: It is react, but hows ur background ? Are u using react-router ? How's ur webpack ? Any more useful information ?

Comment: Can you give more details about the project structure?

Comment: U should probably use the server http handling. I dont know what server u use. I know about apache, which is (mod_rewrite)[https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/] just read this website or see some tutorials, u gonna see it's not that hard

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed that with adding this.

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => {window.location.href="/main.html"}} />
```

workaround but its okay for me.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question. You were asking how to start your project with a file other than `index.html`. What was your solution for that?

Comment: As i ask above, i just want to start  with xxx.html.  My "/" route redirect to component <HomePageComponent/>. but i have found a good html template from themeforest . and decided to use this html file. Actually i want to show thisi html file without putting /main.html  should be start with myhost.com rather than myhost.com/main.html. but i couldnt. finally i just redirect with Route. would be better without ending with main.html but it is ok. you can still propose better one. thank you.